# Writing a text editor for the console

Tags: console

I'd like to be able to have an editing area with a heads up display like found in vi or emacs. Are there libraries that will allow me to do this? No need for cross platform support, Linux only is fine. My preferred language is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).